# Why is there a performance difference between these two reverse loops?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

[Benchmarks](http://jsperf.com/iterate-array)

Note: To run just the following two tests on that benchmark suite, click on `Basic reverse for loop` and `Falsy reverse for loop`.

The ops/sec listed below are on Chrome 32, Win 7 64-bit.

---

This loop

```
for (var i=a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { }  // 1,161,089 ops/sec
```

is much faster than

```
for (var i=a.length; i--;) { }  // 870,837 ops/sec
```

on Chrome 32, Firefox 27, and Opera 12 & 19. They're about equal in IE (5 - 11) and the falsy loop is actually faster in Safari Windows (5.1.7). This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the loop conditional being falsy - there's another benchmark in that suite for that comparison.

The "basic" loop is about 33% faster than the "falsy" loop on Chrome 32, Win 7 64-bit. Why?

Comment: It must have something to do with Javascript engine optimization.  If I were optimizing a Javascript engine, I would look for code patterns like the first example, since that is the most canonical way to write a loop.

Comment: A plausible reason: in the second example, because `I--` is an arbitrary expression (not a bare loop variable), there's no way for Javascript to know how complex that arbitrary expression is (without doing some code analysis); it must evaluate that expression *first*, before evaluating the end-loop condition, so you've taken away an optimization opportunity.

Comment: I've always used the second version myself - I find it more concise

Comment: Most programmers don't expect that form, and using it just to save a few characters costs the next programmer a few seconds of thinking time while they grok what you did.  Don't make future readers of your code think about code structures which should be obvious.

Comment: In Greg Reimer's blog (which I based my tests on), he doesn't even include the "basic" version.

Comment: Well, now you have something you can share with him.

Answer (score 0):

That second loop: `for (var i=a.length; i--;) { }` iterates until `i--` returns false, since that part is written in the condition part of the loop.
`i--` will return false when i equals 0, so the functionality of the two loops is the same.

However, the second loop causes the additional task of casting each of the values between a.length and 0 to a Boolean, which is more time consuming than integer comparison.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't cast the loop conditional (`i--`) to Boolean... it's evaluated as a [falsy](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/) conditional. Also, the benchmarks I posted include a test on `for (var i=a.length; i-->0;) { }` which actually performs a tiny bit (~1%) worse than the falsy version.